# How to get before after comma without using PHP explode()

Tags: php

I know I can do this like following way, but is there a one line method like using regex to get everything before the comma as $first and everything after comma as $second?

```
$data = "m-12,s-52";
$arr = explode(",", $data);
$first = $arr[0];
$second = $arr[1];
```

Comment: sounds like homework.. [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) with 3rd arg true, https://3v4l.org/J55Le

Comment: Thanks Lawrance but I am also getting ht `comma` here! ` echo stristr($data, ',', false);`

Comment: ltrim it, ill ask whats wrong with trusty explode or regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `$first` and `$second` using this one line regex code

```php
$data = "m-12,s-52,s-52";
$beforefirstcomma = preg_replace("/,(.+)/", "", $data);
$afterlastcomma = preg_replace("/(.+),/", "", $data);
$afterfirstcomma = preg_replace("/^[^,]+,+/", "", $data);

// outputs
echo $beforefirstcomma; // m-12
echo "<br>";
echo $afterlastcomma; // s-52
echo "<br>";
echo $afterfirstcomma; // s-52,s-52
```

**Final Note**
I still recommend using `explode()` because it is more efficient and performant than running `preg_replace()` multiple times on the `$data` string.